# Find MahApps Metro title bar color

Tags: wpf, titlebar, mahapps.metro

I am using `MahApps Metro` and i'm trying to get to `TitleBar` color to use it with other controllers:

[image]

In `App.xaml` file all i can see is:

```
<ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/BaseLight.xaml" />
```

Which is the `theme` name, i can change `BaseLight` to `Red` for exapmle and my `TitleBar` become `Red`  but i really like this color.
Any suggestions how to find this color ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be

> AccentColorBrush

You can access it like this:

```
<TextBox Background="{DynamicResource AccentColorBrush}" />
```